# JavaScript onClick function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function delete() {
var newwindow;
newwindow=window.open();

}

function edit(){
}
</script>

[...]

   <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Titel</th>
      <th>Ort</th>
      <th>Referenzcode</th>
      <th>Bearbeiten</th>
      <th>L�schen</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <c:forEach items="${vacancies}" var="vac">
          <spring:url value="/vac" htmlEscape="true" var="vacEdit" />
          <spring:url value="/vac/${vac.id}" htmlEscape="true" var="vacDelete" />
          <tr>
              <td><c:out value="${vac.id}"/></td>
              <td><c:out value="${vac.titel}"/></td>
              <td><c:out value="${vac.location}"/></td>
              <td><c:out value="${vac.referenceCode}"/></td>
              <td><input type="button" name="Bearbeiten" value="Edit" onclick="edit();"></td>
              <td><input type="button" name="Loeschen" value="Delete" onclick="delete();"></td>
          </tr>
          </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Google Chrome's JavaScript console throws out these three errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete vacAdmin:23
Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is not defined  vacAdmin:122 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )    vacAdmin:123
```

Any suggestions why the `onclick` method doesn't call or find the `edit()` and `delete()` function?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I'll try it, never used it before

Comment: Otherwise, right click on the browser and share the page source code.

Comment: Didnt found this by using the search bar, sry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use reserved language words like `delete` as identifiers. In javascript [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is operator that removes object properties.

Rename you function to something like `deleteVacancy` this and it will work:

```
<input type="button" name="Loeschen" value="Delete" onclick="deleteVacancy();">
```

Comment: AH! That was the mistake, thank you.